JetBrains Gateway: Cannot connect to remote host: Connection refused: no further information
I can't connect to JetBrains CLion (2024.1) using JetBrains Gateway (2024.1). Trying to connect to a Linux machine from a Windows machine to use CLion IDE remotely. Error pops up when correct IP address is put in:
When using JetBrains Gateway (2024.1), I am trying to connect to a Linux machine running Clion (2024.1) from a Windows computer since Remote Desktop Connection goes really slow. In JetBrains Gateway, I click on "SSH" > "New Connection" > "Open Settings" and try to configure my remote session from there. I type in the remote machine's ip address where it asks for "Host:", my username (as returned by the whoami command from the command line on the linux machine), set "Authentication type:" to "Password" since I don't know what the other options mean, and "Port" to 22 since that was the default. When I hit the "Test Connection" button, the following error shows up:
Connection to username@000.000.000.000:22
Cannot connect to remote host: Connection refused: no further information
The terminal on the linux machine has the following however:
username@lab-computer:~$
Any idea why this could be happening? I am testing on the same network as the school so it is probably not a firewall issue, and I can remote login using Remote Desktop Connection from the same Windows computer.
I suspect it might have something to do with "lab-computer" not being my ip address, but I am not sure, as linux is new to me.
Any help would be appreciated, as I'm new to JetBrains stuff.
Thanks!

From the Linux box, do you get any output from netstat -ltn | grep 22?

I've just had a similar issue as well after upgrading to 2024.01 on both WebStorm and Intellij.
I found this issue on JetBrains YouTrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-63050/Incorrect-base64-in-.pub-file-leads-to-connection-termination
that mentions the .pub file (if present) in your users (on windows) .ssh folder failing to parse and therefore terminating the connection.
So as a temporary workaround try moving your .pub file somewhere else.
I've also had my known_hosts file corrupted, which was apparently also causing this issue, so if moving your .pub file doesn't fix your issue, try moving that as well.
